# A test statistic that equals a constant under $H_{0}$

Tags: likelihood-ratio

I was designing a hypothesis test, using the likelihood ratio test, and I found out that, under $H_{0}$, the test statistic $\Lambda$ equals the same constant $k$ no matter what the observations may be. Does that mean that the rejection region is of the following form? $$ C=\{ x, \Lambda(x)<k\}$$

Comment: Please show full details. I ask because I expect it's the same potential error as your previous question. A pity you deleted instead of responding to clarify there.

Comment: @Glen_b What I did was the following: I wrote the likelihood ratio test, I pluged in the estimators of the the parameters (Which are function of the observations), I then noticed that under $H_{0}$ the test statistic always equal the same constant $k$ no matter what the observations may be, I did a simulation on Matlab and all the values of $\Lambda$ was close to 0 (values were of the form $x,xxx \times 10^{-16}$). realising this result was always true when $H_0$ is verified, I was wondering how can I extract the p-value, and since $\Lambda$ doesn't seem to have a distribution ...

Comment: (at least to my knowledge), now that I look at my question, I can see that it's wrong

Comment: Details should go in the question, but you're omitting the very details that would let us see *why* you have a constant value under $H_0$ (we're not mind-readers). In particular I suspect you're treating the $L_0$ term (ie. the one under H0) in the LRT statistic wrong (e.g. plugging in ML estimates derived under $H_1$). Please add complete details of what you did into your question, so we can see what you are doing.  Alternatively if you know what went wrong, please add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your rejection region is either everything or it's nothing. The test has either a 100% false positive rate or a 100% false negative rate.

Comment: Somehow I suspect the problem occurred earlier...

Comment: @eric_kernfeld what do you mean?

Comment: @ToneyShields a likelihood ratio statistic should be a statistic. As in: it is a function of the data. If data can't change it, it's a dumb LR. You should check the assumptions of a likelihood ratio test. All kinds of problems surface when testing a hypothesis about, say, a uniform(0, $\theta$) distribution. Think about "why" and what the density function is, and so on.